# Place the legend in a fixed position based on the coordinates

Tags: plotting, legending

The **Placed** function can put a legend on a **Plot**, but the position will be changed when I change the **ImageSize**.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.1, 0.9}], 
ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Is there a way to fix the legend position by giving coordinates? For example, let the legend left-top corner fix at point (1,1), or let the spacings between the legend and frame be 0.1 image width and 0.1 height.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen `Scaled` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that uses the **Scaled** function.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Scaled[{0.1, 0.9}], {0, 1}}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```